# Calculate distances and find closest location to the location of flooding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two datasets with different lengths (see below) with lat/lon for different dates. I want to use each location of flooding and calculate distance from that to all storm surge locations for each date and select the location of smallest distance. For example: in first dataset I have one entry for `1979-01-24` and in second dataset I have five entries for same date. I want to use the location `coor (flood)` from the first dataset and calculate distances to each entries in second dataset and then select the location (with all data) which is closest to the `coor (flood)`.

```py
flood_df.head()

   lon_flood  lat_flood  Percentiles_moisture_flood  Percentiles_precip_flood  Percentiles_discharge_flood  Sum_perc_flood           coor (flood) Hazard_start
0  -80.78125   25.15625                    0.777194                  0.849623                     0.960600        2.587417  (-80.78125, 25.15625)   1979-01-24
1  -80.65625   25.28125                    0.694346                  0.960126                     0.980657        2.635129  (-80.65625, 25.28125)   1979-04-29
2  -80.40625   25.28125                    0.974628                  0.974852                     0.933265        2.882745  (-80.40625, 25.28125)   1979-09-03
3  -80.40625   25.28125                    0.994069                  0.995098                     0.995548        2.984716  (-80.40625, 25.28125)   1979-09-12
4  -80.40625   25.28125                    0.895422                  0.998689                     0.997343        2.891454  (-80.40625, 25.28125)   1981-08-16
```

```py
surge_df.head()

   latitude  longitude  surge        Date  Percentiles       coor (surge)
0    25.737    -80.142   96.0  1979-01-24     0.981429  (-80.142, 25.737)
1    25.591    -80.142   91.0  1979-01-24     0.978333  (-80.142, 25.591)
2    25.942    -80.112  103.0  1979-01-24     0.985455  (-80.112, 25.942)
3    25.415    -80.171   88.0  1979-01-24     0.977000  (-80.171, 25.415)
4    25.327    -80.229   95.0  1979-01-24     0.982143  (-80.229, 25.327)
```

I am using following code to calculate the distances and it's giving me the distances but I also want to have their associated percentiles of surge and other rows.

```py
# libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# progress bar
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm, trange

# dealing with date and time
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# for calculating distance
import haversine as hs

# calculate distance
distance_coord_flood_surge = []

for i, r in zip(locations_flood_surge['coor (flood)'], locations_flood_surge['coor (surge)'] ):
    # print(i, r)
    distance = hs.haversine(i, r)
    distance_coord_flood_surge.append(distance)
```

I also tried as below but still I am not getting all the information.

```py
# find nearest storm surge location to flood location
# dataframe 
surge_flood_dist_df = pd.DataFrame()
        
# get the beginning and ending date of an event
for i in tqdm(zip(range(len(events_dates_2018)))):
    start_date = events_dates_2018['Hazard_start'].iloc[i]
    end_date = events_dates_2018['Hazard_end'].iloc[i]
    
    #lat and lon
    # coord_flood = flood_vars_output_df['coor (flood)']
 
    # get the first and last date of the window
    first_window_date = start_date - timedelta(days=1)
    last_window_date = end_date + timedelta(days=1)
    # get the date range of the window
    window_dates = pd.date_range(first_window_date, last_window_date)
    
    # get the values of the window
    window_values_surge = surge_df.loc[surge_df.index.intersection(window_dates)]

    window_values_flood = flood_df.loc[flood_vars_output_df.index.intersection(window_dates)]

    # get the closest storm surge location to the flood location
    for j, k in zip(window_values_flood['coor (flood)'], window_values_surge['coor (surge)']):
        distance = hs.haversine(j, k)

        # select the closest storm surge location to the flood location and append to the dataframe 
        surge_flood_dist_df.append(distance)
```

Could you please help me on how to do it? I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample as plain text. Try `print(surge_df.head(5)` and `print(flood_df.head(5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, merge your two dataframes on date columns then compute the haversine distance and keep only the closest distance for a same date:

```
from haversine import haversine_vector

# Merge
out = flood_df.merge(surge_df, left_on='Hazard_start', right_on='Date', how='left')

# Haversine
out['haversine'] = haversine_vector(out[['lon_flood', 'lat_flood']], 
                                    out[['longitude', 'latitude']])

# Select the closest
out = out.loc[out.groupby('Hazard_start', dropna=False)['haversine']
                 .rank(method='dense').fillna(1)
                 .loc[lambda x: x==1].index]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   lon_flood  lat_flood  Percentiles_moisture_flood  Percentiles_precip_flood  Percentiles_discharge_flood  Sum_perc_flood           coor (flood) Hazard_start  latitude  longitude  surge        Date  Percentiles       coor (surge)  haversine
4  -80.78125   25.15625                    0.777194                  0.849623                     0.960600        2.587417  (-80.78125, 25.15625)   1979-01-24    25.327    -80.229   95.0  1979-01-24     0.982143  (-80.229, 25.327)  61.487236
5  -80.65625   25.28125                    0.694346                  0.960126                     0.980657        2.635129  (-80.65625, 25.28125)   1979-04-29       NaN        NaN    NaN         NaN          NaN                NaN        NaN
6  -80.40625   25.28125                    0.974628                  0.974852                     0.933265        2.882745  (-80.40625, 25.28125)   1979-09-03       NaN        NaN    NaN         NaN          NaN                NaN        NaN
7  -80.40625   25.28125                    0.994069                  0.995098                     0.995548        2.984716  (-80.40625, 25.28125)   1979-09-12       NaN        NaN    NaN         NaN          NaN                NaN        NaN
8  -80.40625   25.28125                    0.895422                  0.998689                     0.997343        2.891454  (-80.40625, 25.28125)   1981-08-16       NaN        NaN    NaN         NaN          NaN                NaN        NaN
```

**Update**

> Is there a way to use a time window on surge_df based on flood_df (such as allowing few days before and after the Hazard_start) to calculate the distances within the window and select values with minimum distance.

Use `how='cross'` as parameter of `merge` to create the cartesian product of dataframes then filter rows according a time window:

```
# You can remove pd.to_datetime if 'Date' and 'Hazard_start' are already datetime64
# Adjust the windows, here 3 days
between_dates = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Date']).sub(pd.to_datetime(x['Hazard_start'])).abs() < pd.Timedelta(days=3)

out = flood_df.merge(surge_df, how='cross').loc[between_dates]
```

Comment: The second part is giving me an error:
```ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key```

Comment: The algorithm was theoretical. I updated my answer with a real code according your sample. Can you check it please?

Comment: One more thing, I am not getting the distances and associated data for all rows. I have 297 rows in `flood_df` and 2232 rows in `surge_df`. Do you know how can I get the data from `surge_df` for all 279 entries in `flood_df`?

Comment: Use `how='left'` as parameter of `merge`.

Comment: It is still giving me the same number of rows.

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: Now it is giving me 341 rows and many NAs. Is there a way to use a time window on `surge_df` based on `flood_df` (such as allowing few days before and after the `Hazard_start`) to calculate the distances within the window and select values with minimum distance.

Comment: Updated related to your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be working now. Just a minor issue, I am getting some repeated rows for some dates. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: For a same `Hazard_start`??? It should be not possible due to `groupby` Can you be more precise?

Comment: Yes, for the same `Hazard_start`. I am getting multiple duplicated rows.

Comment: I understand why: for rows from `flood_df` that have no match date on `surge_df` I use `fillna(1)` to keep this rows on the final output. If you remove `.fillna(1)`, I think it should work but not guarantee to have all dates from `flood_df`.

Comment: I tried removing `.fillna(1)` and it's still giving me the same results.